# Objectively speaking, what is the expected standard to prepare for an interview as network admin?

Tags: firewalls, password-policy, sso, administration

I have an interview middle of next month for a position as network admin.

As I understand things, clients are running Windows but some servers may be running Linux.

What is the expected standard in network security?

Comment: OSI Layers (and security measures for every layer), VPNs, VLANs, Firewalls, IPS/IDS are the very basics imho.

Comment: Try going through some of [these topics](https://pentesterlab.com/bootcamp).

Comment: Cisco has a whole line of certs for network security. I'd look at their study material.

Comment: Still opinion. Still super broad, too. The minimum is going to be up to your interviewer. Seriously, go through the entry-level Cisco security books. That's the expected standard for this sort of thing.

Comment: Ok, although one could assume that there is a minimum that could suit more then one interviewer so the magic words here would be "expected standard" :)